# How to Filter DataGrid with 2 dates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagrid

I was wondering how to filter the datagrid.

I have tried several times to make a filter using the following line.

```
Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\VS\NaiaPOS\myDB.accdb")
        Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim sql As String
        Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Try
            con.Open()
            sql = "Select * FROM rooms where [end] = ?"
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", minus & " and" & ender)

            da.Fill(ds)

            GridSummary.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            ds = Nothing
            da = Nothing
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

This is my error:

```
The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.
```

Can you pin point me to the right door to achieve this? I wanted to select the last 2 days from my table.

I have a column name "end" under table "rooms".

Comment: Thanks you gave me an idea on what I am missing. Also can you help me display specific columns?

Comment: Replace the '*' with the column names you want returned. Ex. `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM rooms where` ... etc.

Comment: I tried my sql querry on my codes above and it display all the columns and rows, now I created this querry so I can display certain rows and columns "sql = "Select roomnumber, type, status, rate, [max], start, [end] FROM rooms where [end] = ?""  but it display nothing... Any more advice, also I had updated my paramaters

Comment: What is '?' Try using `Select type, status, rate FROM rooms where [end] = @end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not setting the SelectCommand property of a dataadapter before calling fill, will cause the error.

```
da.SelectCommand = cmd
```